# Outbound IPs whitelist in B2B

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule4

I have Outbound IP range from partner system(server) whose HTTPS URL we are trying to connect to transfer files but since no APIs are involved , how to check if IP's are whitelisted or is it any way to Whitelist that IP range in anypoint Studio7 using Mule4

Not finding way to do it via Anypoint studio as my code is deployed locally and not on any CloudHub or on-premise as of now, as its just a POC

Answer (score 0):

It is the other way around. The other side, which exposes the HTTPS service you are connecting to, restricts access to their service by whitelisting some IPs. If your IP, from where you connect to the service, is whitelisted, then you will be able to connect to it. If not, you might not even get an error response. It is up to the side whitelisting, which is usually the server.